# How can I initiate react to reload after a data change on the node js side?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So I added a calendar to react which changes the workout data to a specific date.  When I change the date the data does change correctly.  If I refresh the react web pages I get the updated data.  I'm just a little confused on how to have node js initiate the data update in react.  After changing the data I have node emitting to this socket...

```
import { format } from 'date-fns'
import ScrapeExperienceLevel from './ScrapeExperienceLevel'

export default (websockets, queue, timer, workouts, scrapeExperienceLevel) => {
websockets.on('connection', socket => {
socket.on('joinRoom', roomName => {
  socket.join(roomName)
})
socket.on('leaveRoom', roomName => {
  socket.leave(roomName)
})
setInterval(function(){
  socket.emit('GetCheckedInMemebers', queue.dump()); 
}, 3000);
socket.on('initScreen', screen => {
  const screenWorkouts = workouts.current.filter(workout => workout.station == screen)

  socket.emit('screenInfo', screenWorkouts)
  socket.emit('queueInfo', queue.screen(screen - 1))
  socket.emit('timer', { time: timer.formatTime().formattedTime })
})

//  code in question
socket.on('GetWorkoutDate', async function (date) {
  await workouts.getNewWorkouts(date.date)
  const screenWorkouts = workouts.current.filter(workout => workout.station == 1)
  socket.emit('UpdateWorkouts', screenWorkouts)
})
socket.on('initAdmin', () => {
  socket.emit('queue', queue.dump())
  socket.emit('timer', { time: timer.formatTime().formattedTime })
})
socket.on('initOverview', () => {
  socket.emit('workouts', workouts.current)
  socket.emit('queue', queue.dump())
  socket.emit('timer', { time: timer.formatTime().formattedTime })
})
socket.on('addUser', async (person) => {
  if(typeof person.member_id == 'undefined')
    person.member_id = ''
  else{
    person.experiencelevel = await scrapeExperienceLevel.getExperienceLevel(person.member_id)
    person.firstname = person.firstname + ' '
  }
  queue.add(person, timer)
  websockets.emit('queue', queue.dump())
})
socket.on('removeUser', ({ group, person, list }) => {
  queue.remove(group, person, list)
  websockets.emit('queue', queue.dump())
})
socket.on('reorder', waiting => {
  queue.reorder(waiting)
  websockets.emit('queue', queue.dump())
})
socket.on('toggleTimer', () => {
  if (timer.isRunning()) {
    timer.pause()
  } else {
    timer.start()
  }
})
})
}
```

Here's my Screen page's react...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { defaultTo } from 'ramda'

import './styles.css'

class Screen extends Component {
  state = {
    time: '',
    rest: false,
    workout: [],
    queue: [],
  }

  UpdateTimer = ({ time, rest }) => {
    this.setState({ time, rest })
  }

  UpdateScreenInfo = ({ data }) => {
    this.setState({ workout: defaultTo({}, data[0]) })
  }

  UpdateQueueInfo = ({ data }) => {
    this.setState({ queue: defaultTo({}, data) })
  }

  UpdateQueue = ({ queue, screenNumber }) => {
    this.setState({ queue: defaultTo({}, queue[screenNumber - 1]) })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const screenNumber = this.props.match.params.id
    const { socket } = this.props

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      socket.emit('joinRoom', 'screens')
      socket.emit('initScreen', screenNumber)
    })
    socket.on('timer', ({ time, rest }) => this.UpdateTimer({ time, rest }))
    socket.on('screenInfo', data => this.UpdateScreenInfo({ data }))
    socket.on('queueInfo', data => this.UpdateQueueInfo({ data }))
    socket.on('queue', ({ queue }) => this.UpdateQueue({ queue, screenNumber }))
    //socket.on('UpdateWorkouts', (updatedData) => this.UpdateWorkoutsData(updatedData))
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const { socket } = this.props

    socket.off('timer', this.UpdateTimer)
    socket.off('screenInfo', this.UpdateScreenInfo)
    socket.off('queueInfo', this.UpdateQueueInfo)
    socket.off('queue', this.UpdateQueue)
  }

  renderMovement = (movement, equipment) => {
    if (!movement) return <noscript />

    return (
      <div className="screenMove">
        {equipment && `${equipment.title} `}
        {movement.title}
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { time, rest, queue } = this.state
    const { workout } = this.props
    const variation = defaultTo({}, workout.variation)
    const person1 = defaultTo({}, queue[0])
    const person2 = defaultTo({}, queue[1])

    return (      
      <main className="screenWrapper">
        <div className="screenHeader">
          <span className="screenFirstUser">
            {(() => {
              if (person1.experiencelevel === 'novice') {
                //  light purple
                return (
                  <div style={{color:'#BF5FFF', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'inline-block'}}>{person1.firstname}</div>
                )
              } else if (person1.experiencelevel === 'beginner') {
                //   light blue
                return (
                  <div style={{color:'#87CEFA', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'inline-block'}}>{person1.firstname}</div>
                )
              } else if (person1.experiencelevel === 'intermediate') {
                return (
                  <div style={{color:'orange', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'inline-block'}}>{person1.firstname}</div>
                )
              } else if (person1.experiencelevel === 'advanced') {
                //  gym green
                return (
                  <div style={{color:'#93C90E', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'inline-block'}}>{person1.firstname}</div>
                )
              }else if (person1.experiencelevel === 'expert') {
                return (
                  <div style={{color:'red', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'inline-block'}}>{person1.firstname}</div>
                )
              }
            })()}
          </span>
          <span className={`screenTimer alt ${rest ? 'rest' : ''}`}>{time ? time : '0:00'}</span>
          <span className="screenSecondUser">
          {(() => {
              if (person2.experiencelevel === 'novice') {
                //    light purple
                return (
                  <div style={{color:'#BF5FFF', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'inline-block'}}>{person2.firstname}</div>
                )
              } else if (person2.experiencelevel === 'beginner') {
                //  light blue
                return (
                  <div style={{color:'#87CEFA', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'inline-block'}}>{person2.firstname}</div>
                )
              } else if (person2.experiencelevel === 'intermediate') {
                return (
                  <div style={{color:'orange', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'inline-block'}}>{person2.firstname}</div>
                )
              } else if (person2.experiencelevel === 'advanced') {
                //   gym green
                return (
                  <div style={{color:'#93C90E', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'inline-block'}}>{person2.firstname}</div>
                )
              }else if (person2.experiencelevel === 'expert') {
                return (
                  <div style={{color:'red', fontWeight: 'bold', display: 'inline-block'}}>{person2.firstname}</div>
                )
              }
            })()}
          </span>
        </div>
        <p className="screenVariation">{variation.title}</p>
        <div className="screenMoves">
          {this.renderMovement(workout.movementOne, workout.equipmentOne)}
          {this.renderMovement(workout.movementTwo, workout.equipmentTwo)}
          {this.renderMovement(workout.movementThree, workout.equipmentThree)}
        </div>
      </main>
    )
  }
}

export default Screen
```

Also found the parent component Daniele enlightened me about.  Now I'm sharing 1 socket connection throughout all the components.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { path } from 'ramda'
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client'
import { defaultTo } from 'ramda'

import './index.css'
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'

import store from './redux/store'
import Admin from './screens/Admin'
import Screens from './screens/Screens'
import Auth from './screens/Auth'
import BackScreen from './screens/Screens/Back'
import FrontScreen from './screens/Screens/Front'

const socket = openSocket(`http://${window.location.hostname}:${process.env.REACT_APP_WEBSOCKET_PORT}`)

function mapState(state) {
  return {
    loggedIn: path(['conf', 'loggedIn'], state),
  }
}

class App extends Component {        
  state = {
    workout: []
  }

  static propTypes = {
    loggedIn: PropTypes.bool,
  }

  componentDidMount() {          
    socket.on('UpdateWorkouts', (workout) => { console.log(workout[0]); this.setState({ workout: defaultTo({}, workout[0]) }) })
  }

  render() {
    const { loggedIn } = this.props
    const workout = this.state
    
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          {!loggedIn && <Route path="/" component={(props) => <Auth socket={socket} {...props} /> }/> }
          <Route exact path="/admin" component={(props) => <Admin socket={socket} {...props} /> } />
          <Route path="/s/back" component={(props) => <BackScreen socket={socket} {...props} /> } />
          <Route path="/s/front" component={(props) => <FrontScreen socket={socket} {...props} /> } />
          <Route path="/s/:id" component={(props) => <Screens {...props} socket={socket} workout={workout} /> } />
          <Redirect to={'/s/1'} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

const ConnectedApp = connect(mapState)(App)
const rootEl = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedApp />
  </Provider>,
  rootEl,
)
```

Here's my Admin page.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import { Button, Grid, Header, Dimmer, Loader } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import { defaultTo } from 'ramda'

import './styles.css'

import WaitingList from './WaitingList'
import Stations from './Stations'
import AddUserModal from './AddUserModal'

class Admin extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
    time: '',
    rest: false,
    data: {
      waiting: [],
      queue: [],
    },
    startDate: new Date(),
    showAddUserModal: false,
  }

  handleChange = date => {
    const { socket } = this.props

    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    })
    socket.emit('GetWorkoutDate', { date })
  }

  UpdateTimer = ({ time, rest }) => {
    this.setState({ time, rest })
  }

  UpdateQueue = ({ data }) => {
    this.setState({ queue: defaultTo({}, data) })
  }

  GetCheckedInMemebers = ({ data }) => {
    this.setState({ data })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { socket } = this.props   

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      socket.emit('initAdmin')
    })
    socket.on('timer', ({ time, rest }) => this.UpdateTimer({ time, rest }))
    socket.on('queue', data => this.UpdateQueue({ data }))
    socket.on('GetCheckedInMemebers', data => this.GetCheckedInMemebers({ data }))
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const { socket } = this.props

    socket.off('timer', this.UpdateTimer)
    socket.off('queue', this.UpdateQueue)
    socket.off('GetCheckedInMemebers', this.GetCheckedInMemebers)
  }

  addPersonToWaitingList = person => {
    const { socket } = this.props

    socket.emit('addUser', person)
  }

  removePersonFromList = (groupIndex, personIndex, list) => {
    const { socket } = this.props

    socket.emit('removeUser', { group: groupIndex, person: personIndex, list: list })
  }

  reorderWaitingList = waiting => {
    const { data } = this.state
    const { socket } = this.props

    this.setState({ data: { ...data, waiting } })
    socket.emit('reorder', waiting)
  }

  toggleTimer = () => {
    const { socket } = this.props
    
    socket.emit('toggleTimer')
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, rest, time, data, showAddUserModal } = this.state

    return (
      <Fragment>
        change workout date&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<DatePicker
        dateFormat="M/d/yy"
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
        <Grid container columns={2} divided id="adminWrapper">
          <Grid.Row className="fGrow">
            <Grid.Column className="listWrapper">
              <Header size="huge" textAlign="center">
                Queue
                <Button positive floated="right" onClick={() => this.setState({ showAddUserModal: true })}>
                  Add
                </Button>
              </Header>
              <WaitingList
                className="adminList"
                waiting={data.waiting}
                reorder={this.reorderWaitingList}
                removeFromList={this.removePersonFromList}
              />
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column className="listWrapper">
              <Header size="huge" textAlign="center">
                Stations
              </Header>
              <Stations className="adminList" queue={data.queue} 
                removeFromList={this.removePersonFromList}
              />
            </Grid.Column>
          </Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Row>
            <Button fluid color={rest ? 'red' : 'blue'} onClick={this.toggleTimer}>
              <span>{time ? time : '0:00'}</span>
            </Button>
          </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
        <AddUserModal
          show={showAddUserModal}
          handleClose={() => this.setState({ showAddUserModal: false })}
          addUser={this.addPersonToWaitingList}
          setLoading={isLoading => this.setState({ loading: isLoading })}
          loading={loading}
        />
        <Dimmer active={loading} page>
          <Loader />
        </Dimmer>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default Admin
```

New to node and react.  Appreciate the guidance!

Edit:  The calendar (date picker) is on another react page.  GetWorkoutDate is being called.  However, react never gets the data from the emit socket.emit('UpdateWorkouts', screenWorkouts).  I verified the everything works correctly except getting the new data to update the react state.

Final Edit:
So for some reason I was not able to send the workout through props for the Screen page.  Although, it is the correct way for react there just must be something going on with my environment.  Here's what I did get working for me.  When Screen page loads it loads the workout.  Then I just added settimeout to repeat getting the workout every 5 secs.

```
socket.on('initScreen', async screen => {
  setInterval(async function(){
    const screenWorkouts = await workouts.current.filter(workout => workout.station == screen)

    socket.emit('screenInfo', screenWorkouts)
  }, 5000)
  socket.emit('queueInfo', queue.screen(screen - 1))
  socket.emit('timer', { time: timer.formatTime().formattedTime })
})
```

What's weird is after sending the workout to screens between 3 and 8 times correctly eventually it sends an empty array.  So to prevent the workout from updating when it's empty I check it for length before I try and update the state.

```
UpdateScreenInfo = ({ data }) => {
  if(data.length !== 0)
    this.setState({ workout: defaultTo({}, data[0]) })
```

I'm awarding Daniele the points since they are about to expire and Daniele helped so much!

Comment: you using redux?

Comment: Yes, it's using redux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that each time you call `openSocket` you open a new connection to the server. Looking at your server code it seems that your `'GetWorkoutDate'` message handler replies with `'UpdateWorkouts'` message on the same socket connection; the problem is that `'UpdateWorkouts'` is received by the react component sending the `'GetWorkoutDate'` message and not by other react components due they open a new connection each.

The proper way to handle with WebSockets in a react app where more components needs to access the WebSocket is to open it only in the root component and passing it to child components as a property. Something like:

```
MainComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Open the socket only in the main component
    this.socket = openSocket(...);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.socket.close();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* pass the socket as property to child components;
            this can be repeated with all nested sub-component */}
        <ChildComponent socket={this.socket}>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { socket } = this.props;

    // create the required handlers and store them
    this.handler = data => { /* do what you need with data */ };

    // add the handlers to the socket
    socket.on("message", this.handler);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const { socket } = this.props;

    // remove the handlers from the socket
    socket.off("message", this.handler);
  }
}
```

By this way you open a single connection and you share it between all components, now you can send messages to the server from a component and handle the response message on any other component.

**Edit** after last question update:

Two things:

1. the parent component is the root `App` component ok, but I can't still understand which is the component which emits the `'GetWorkoutDate'` message (I was thinking it was the `Screen` 's parent component, but it seems I'm wrong); probably to find final solution we need to clarify this;
2. you are passing the socket (as a property) to the `Route` component, not to the `Screen` component: you need to change your routes as follows

`<Route path="/s/:id" component={() => <Screens socket={socket} />} />`

I checked better last version of your `Screen` component: you can't do this in `componentDidMount` method:

```
socket.on('timer', ({ time, rest }) => this.setState({ time, rest }))
```

you need to store the reference of the handler function in order to remove it later in `componentWillUnmount` method.

You can't do this in `componentWillUnmount` method:

```
socket.close();
```

now you have only one connection shared between all components of your app, if you close it once, you close it forever.

The strategy is: in `componentDidMount` method:

1. for each message (or more on general for each event), to create a handler function and store its reference
2. attache the referenced handler function to the desired message (or more in general, to the desired event)

then, in `componentWillUnmount` method:

3. to detach the handler function (throug the reference we still have) from the message (or more in general from the event),

by this way each time the component is mounted it starts listening on the desired messages/events, each time the component is unmounted it stops doing it and no actions will be performed on it while not mounted be the message/event handlers.

**Edit:**

1. Having circular `import` dependency is a bad idea: it's better to remove any `var App = require('./index')` (or similar) from child component files
2. But moreover, if the purpose of `handleChange` is only to emit something on the ws you don't need a so complicated design pattern: you can access the socket from `Admin` Component.

Probably what you need is

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // App component will never unmount: the reference for unmounting is not required
    socket.on('UpdateWorkouts', ([workout]) => this.setState({ workout }));
  }

  render() {
    const { workout } = this.state;

    return (
      ...
      <Route path="/s/:id" component={props => <Screens {...props, socket, workout} />} />
      ...
    );
  }
}

class Screen extends Component {
  render() {
    const { time, rest, queue } = this.state;
    const { workout } = this.props;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Edited question with more info. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please check my updated answer based on your new info @AndrewKloos ? Thank you

Comment: Still a little fuzzy parent child components.  So you're saying the parent and child connections are on different sockets?  I'll post my whole websockets file.

Comment: Sorry @AndrewKloos ; are you calling `openSocket(...)` more than once in your client? If you add a line `this.socket.on('UpdateWorkouts', (updatedData) => this.handleUpdateWorkouts(updatedData));` immediately before the line `this.socket.emit('GetWorkoutDate', { date })` does it prints something? If both the answers are "yes" it means we found the problem, then I'll update my answer with a final solution.

Comment: Each client file opens a socket connection but only once per client file.  Tried adding that line however it's in another client file and doesn't know what this.handleUpdateWorkouts is.

Comment: Yes sorry @AndrewKloos I was meaning a line `this.socket.on('UpdateWorkouts', (updatedData) => console.log(updatedData))`

Comment: So ran this instead...     this.socket.on('UpdateWorkouts', (updatedData) => { console.log('got here');this.setState({ workout: updatedData[0] })})  and received got here on client!

Comment: I knew there was something fundamentally wrong with the current set up.  Thanks for setting me straight.  i'll implement tmw and get back with you.  Appreciate your time!

Comment: I updated my code with your suggested code but getting TypeError: instance.render is not a function.  It seems upset with my placement of the child component.  I updated my question code to show how I implemented your suggested code.

Comment: Each component **must** implement a `render` method. That's the source of your last problem (I omitted it for shortness). Anyway as you described your problem it seems that in your program `Screen` is the child component and the parent component is the one which sends the `'GetWorkoutDate'` message to the websocket. @AndrewKloos

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I went over your code bunch and appreciate the education!  I found the parent component in my project but I'm not passing the socket correctly because it shows up undefined in the children.  Feel like I'm almost there tho.  I updated my question with the parent code.  Thanks for your patience with me.

Comment: We are closer to the solution @AndrewKloos , but probably we still need something more

Comment: So the GetworkoutDate comes from another child... the Admin page.  Which is loading the shared socket connection now after implementing the changes <Route exact path="/admin" component={() => <Admin socket={socket} /> } />!!!!  Will implement the rest of the handlers shortly.

Comment: That was I was suspecting @AndrewKloos , now we have another problem: when client and server exchange the `'GetWorkoutDate'` and `'UpdateWorkouts'` messages, the rendered component is `Admin`, so no handlers from `Screens` component is listening; the best solution is to handle `'UpdateWorkouts'` message in `App` component (which is listening also when the rendered component is `Admin`) and pass the handled result to `Screen` component as another property

Comment: Ok, I implement the shared socket between the components and it's working great now.  Woot!  Having some trouble passing the date change to the main app component.  Updated my question with that error.  I'm going to award you the points tmw for all the time you've spent on this with me.  If you could give me final guidance I will be forever in your debt!!

Comment: Hi @AndrewKloos I wrote the code I described in my previous comment

Comment: Ok, most of the code is working now.  I updated the question with that latest version and probs.  Thanks so much for your help.  I wanted to award you the points before they expire.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling componentDidMount function when socket emits UpdateWorkouts which is causing the loop. You should not call componentDidMount function of a react component, react handles the lifecycles methods itself. You can have another method to handle updates as following.

```
handleUpdateWorkouts = (updatedData) => {
   //Update your workout, queue etc. whatever you update
   this.setState({updatedData})

}
```

And assign this function as callback to on "UpdateWorkouts" events.

```
this.socket.on('UpdateWorkouts', (updatedData) => this.handleUpdateWorkouts(updatedData));
```

Comment: Thanks man.  I implemented your suggested code and react is still not updating the data without a refresh.  Edited to show new code changes.

Comment: Did you check if defaultTo({}, updatedData[0]) is what you expect it to be. Try outputting it  to see if data actually comes from socket. And how do you display the workouts? You should use this.state.workout to display workouts so the view gets updated when state is updated.

Comment: So I did a console.log on the data from the node side and it's correct.  I am loading workouts from state but I'll put up the whole react file so you don't need to guess.

Comment: Could you put  console.log(updatedData); inside handleUpdateWorkouts() and console.log(workout); in render function and emit update event from server. Code looks fine, so there might be some problem with callback on socket.on. Please check the output of updatedData and the state.workout in render function after an update.

Comment: hmmmm.  added console.log(updatedData) to handleUpdateWorkouts but get no entry in chrome's console.

Comment: You have socket = null after handleUpdate function. Could it be closing the socket?

Comment: removed socket = null. no effect.  The console log shows correct data for page load.  but then no entry for date change.  Could this be a problem from this being initiated from another page?

Comment: Another weird thing.  if I change to this.socket.on('UpdateWorkouts', console.log('Got here') ).  I get Got here on page load but not when emitting UpdateWorkouts.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you are emitting `GetWorkoutDate` properly upon the calendar onChange.

```js
this.socket.on('GetWorkoutDate', date); //something like this
```

2. If `getNewWorkouts` function is an async, then use `await`

```js
socket.on('GetWorkoutDate', async function (date) {
    await workouts.getNewWorkouts(date.date) //<----- here
    const screenWorkouts = workouts.current.filter(workout => workout.station == 1)
    console.log(screenWorkouts[0])
    socket.emit('UpdateWorkouts', screenWorkouts)
  })
```

Comment: if not working, then pls share code of how you are emitting `GetWorkoutDate` ... also code around calendar...also code around `workouts` object on server

Comment: Edited question with more info. Thanks!

Comment: ok - as mentioned in my answer can you await on `workouts.getNewWorkouts(date.date)`... else it will emit `UpdateWorkouts` with old data .. and eventually db gets new data and hence you will see updated data in frontend only upon page refresh... .and also code around workouts object on server

Comment: added the await for getNewWorkouts but still not getting call back to execute.  I put the code for getting the workouts but just an api call.

Answer (score 1):

I do have one solution at architect level which is, Return synchronous actions from the nodeJs sockets. So the moment client receive it, just dispatch the action received via socket and then automatically update it.

For eg: if socket returns

```
{
  type: 'actionName',
  data
}
```

then dispatching it directly would result in auto update of subscribed components.